# Boolean field Oracle vs MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, entity-framework, hibernate

I am using hibernate to create tables. In my entity I have following fields. This entity is successfully created when I use MySQL database. but on oracle 10g it throws error

`create table MetaData (ID bigint not null auto_increment, metaDataId varchar(255) not null, parentId bigint not null, locked bit, userId bigint not null, primary key (ID), unique (metaDataId))`

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
@Table(name = "MetaData", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "metaDataId"))
public class MetaData extends SavableEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String metaDataId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long parentId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column
    @Type(type = "boolean")
    private boolean locked;
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: LOCKED is a keyword in oracle. Culd you try another field name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a closer look to the generated SQL syntax you will recognize that the datatype for the field locked and the name of it "locked"

```
create table MetaData (..., **locked bit**, ...)
```

is turned around in comparsion to e.g. the field userId with the datatype bigint

```
create table MetaData (..., **userId bigint not null**, ...)
```

As some databases do not have boolean fields implemented yet you need to write some annotations which help hibernate to perform the conversion.

If you want to store boolean values as T or F use:

```
@Type(type="true_false")
private Boolean active;
```

For storing them as 1 or 0 use:

```
@Type(type="boolean")
private Boolean active;
```

Mr. Jake Trent offer a great post of how to perform hibernate boolean conversions: http://jaketrent.com/post/hibernate-boolean-conversion/

Answer (score 0):

The `DATATYPE` are different in `Oracle`.

Also, `auto_increment` is not in `Oracle`. In `11g` and prior, create a `SEQUENCE` to populate the ID column, in `12c`, use `IDENTITY COLUMNS`.

```
SQL> DROP TABLE metadata PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE MetaData
  2    (
  3      ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  4      metaDataId VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  5      parentId number NOT NULL,
  6      locked number,
  7      userId number NOT NULL,
  8      CONSTRAINT p_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  9      CONSTRAINT u_metadataid UNIQUE (metaDataId)
 10    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

For the `auto_increment` of ID, in `Oracle 10g`, you need to create a `sequence`.

In `12c`, you can have an `IDENTITY COLUMN`.

Comment: I am using 11g so this is not the issue